# How To Cascade a CollectionElement in Hibernate Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I wrote the following object:

```
@Entity
public class Report implements Serializable {

@Id
private String url;

@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE) 
@ElementCollection()
private List<ArrayList<KeyPhrase>> keywordReports = new ArrayList<>();

@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@ElementCollection()
private List<KeyPhrase> allKeyPhrases = new ArrayList<>();

@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@ElementCollection()
private List<KeyPhrase> allOtherPhrases = new ArrayList<>();

@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE) 
@ElementCollection()
private List<KeyPhrase> topGroup = new ArrayList<>();

public Report(String url, List<ArrayList<KeyPhrase>> keywordReports, List<KeyPhrase> allKeyPhrases,
        List<KeyPhrase> allOtherPhrases, List<KeyPhrase> topGroup) {
    this.url = url;
    this.keywordReports = keywordReports;
    this.allKeyPhrases = allKeyPhrases;
    this.allOtherPhrases = allOtherPhrases;
    this.topGroup = topGroup;
}
}
```

When I try to save a new report through the repository, I get the following error message:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing:
```

I've read that the error message points to a problem that can be solved by adding a CASCADE.ALL annotation. However, with the annotations that I'm using I don't know where to specify to cascade. I tried in several annotations, but the compiler always tells me it's an illegal location to specify cascade.

I also unsuccessfully tried to add this annotation:

```
"@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)"
```

FYI, I have another entity in the program where I've done this:

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@ElementCollection()
private List<String> related = new ArrayList<>();
```

And interestingly enough, this one works like a charm.

Can anyone give me a hint how I could solve the cascade issue, or what else might be the problem with my code?

Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you have to specify what is the relation between your Report and KeyPhrase. like
1.`@OneToOne`
2.`@OneToMany`
3.`@ManyToMany`

When you do this you can specify your cascade property. For example.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private List<KeyPhrase> allKeyPhrases = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Hi @pvpkiran, thanks for your comment. I tried this but I'm getting an error because the keyphrase lists are not mapped. I though that's what ElementCollection was for - that you don't have to map the children and can just use them through the parent w/o doing a n-to-n annotation?